# Docusign SDK for Java can be used in a non-web application

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am trying to use the Docusign SDK in a standalone (non-web) application, but the following error is thrown.

```
com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code 401 with response Body: '{"errorCode":"PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED","message":"The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."}'
```

sample code:

```
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
apiClient.setOAuthBasePath("account-d.docusign.com");
OAuth.OAuthToken oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(
        CLIENT_ID, 
        ACCOUNT_ID,
        List.of(OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE),
        getRsaBytes(), TOKEN_EXPIRATION_SECONDS);


apiClient.setAccessToken(oAuthToken.getAccessToken(), oAuthToken.getExpiresIn());

OAuth.UserInfo userInfo = apiClient.getUserInfo(oAuthToken.getAccessToken());

ApiClient apiClientRequest = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
apiClient.addDefaultHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, BEARER_AUTHENTICATION + oAuthToken.getAccessToken());

EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClientRequest);
EnvelopeIdsRequest request = new EnvelopeIdsRequest();
request.addEnvelopeIdsItem("740525a1-6eb9-4045-a634-7e77bd52e474");
EnvelopesInformation status = envelopesApi.listStatus(ACCOUNT_ID, request);
```

It is worth mentioning the following points:

1. My account, integration key and RSA are all correct
2. Consent has already been given for the application
3. The logic of this code works when I use the RestTemplate instead of the ApiClient object

I appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz, i added the code as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

To get JWT working you need to ensure you created the integration key in your developer account and configured it correctly.
https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/

Or, use [Quickstart](https://devcenterv3test.hqtest.tst/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart) to get code that already has it all set up for you.

Comment: Inbar, my integration key for my application was created correctly. I can get the token, the problem occurs when I try to get the list of the status of the envelope
Any idea what is going on?

Comment: you can get a token, but when you try to use the token you get the error "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."?
That can only happen if you get the token in prod/dev env. and try to use it in the other one prod/dev env. Please share your code.

Comment: ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(ApiClient.DEMO_REST_BASEPATH);
      OAuth.OAuthToken oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(CLIENT_ID, 
         ACCOUNT_ID, List.of(OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE, OAuth.Scope_IMPERSONATION),
         getRsaBytes(), TOKEN_EXPIRATION_SECONDS);
    
      EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
      EnvelopeIdsRequest request = new EnvelopeIdsRequest();
      request.addEnvelopeIdsItem("740525a1-6eb9-4045-a634-7e77bd52e474");
      EnvelopesInformation status = envelopesApi.listStatus(ACCOUNT_ID, request);

Comment: It appears still to be a configuration issue. 
Here is what I suggest - go to https://devcenterv3test.hqtest.tst/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart and select Java and you'll get it all configured by our code and you'll get a ZIP downloaded that should just work out of the box. then you can see how it was done and get your own app working.

Comment: Ilbar, 
I've already done tests with quickstart, both java and shell script, both work. The quick start java is done in the java web application format, differently from what I need, that is, a standalone application that only needs to use the Docusign SDK directly.

Comment: Did you use JWT with the quickstart?
and you use the same IK in your standalone that was was created in the quickstart?

Comment: Ilbar, yes i used the same. And even using another application not using quick start, they also don't work

Comment: Ibar, i found the problem. it was necessary to add the code below in the ApiClient configuration. Thanks a lot for the help.      
                                  `apiClientRequest.setAccessToken(oAuthToken.getAccessToken(), oAuthToken.getExpiresIn());`

Answer (score 0):

@Inbar, the code below works perfectly, unlike using the Docusign SDK.

```
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
apiClient.setOAuthBasePath("account-d.docusign.com");
OAuth.OAuthToken oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(
        CLIENT_ID,
        ACCOUNT_ID,
        List.of(OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE),
        getRsaBytes(), TOKEN_EXPIRATION_SECONDS);


OAuth.UserInfo userInfo = apiClient.getUserInfo(oAuthToken.getAccessToken());
OAuth.Account account = userInfo.getAccounts().get(0);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.setBearerAuth(oAuthToken.getAccessToken());

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

String resourceUrl = ApiClient.DEMO_REST_BASEPATH + "/v2.1/accounts/" + account.getAccountId() + "/envelopes/" + ENVELOPE_ID;

ResponseEntity<Envelope> response = restTemplate.exchange(RequestEntity.get(new URI(resourceUrl)).headers(headers).build(), Envelope.class);
```

Comment: This code is using the DocuSign SDK. I can see that. Not sure what is the issue then.

Comment: Please DO NOT create "answers" that are a continuation of your question. Instead, EDIT your question to add more info or to update your question. StackOverflow is not a forum.